# New mysqli connection is not working in My Cpanel but works in my computer

Tags: php, mysql

php code which is functioning very well in my computer but whenever i am uploading my files to my Cpanel not working receiving this error message:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (42000/1044): Access denied for user '*****'@'localhost' to database '*****' in /home/*****/public_html/Admin Panel/db.php on line 3
>       Unable to connect to database [Access denied for user '*****'@'localhost' to database '*****']

My **username** and **password** both are 100% correct but i don't know why i am receiving this.

```
<?php
    $connection=new mysqli('localhost', 'CpanelName_username', 'test.123', 'CpanelName_DB');
    if($connection->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
    }
?>
```

Comment: The error message clearly says that you have provided wrong credential for connecting to your mysql server.

Comment: its working in my localhost (my computer) but not in cpanel

Comment: You have to provide your cpanel hostname,username,password,database and also check whether the user has privilege to connect to that database or not.

Comment: Add privilage to access cpanel IP in your database server

Comment: thanks my ALL PRIVILIGES part in my Cpanel were uncheck.

Comment: Array ( [0] => INSERT command denied to user '*****'@'localhost' for table 'students' ) "Sorry Qurery Failed"     i got this error massgae even i checked all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Check if localhost should be used.

Many shared hosting providers may not have database on the same machine. So check the database hostname and change accordingly.